# Android webserver via usb not wifi

Tags: usb, web-server

I was wondering is there a way to run an android websever via usb? I can find lots of wifi version of this but I would like to use this locally only while the pc is connected to the wifi and have it undetectable. eg via usb.

Does anyone know of any apps/software that this would work on?

Thanks

Paul

Comment: That's rather not a question of the app, but of the connection. You might wish to check [usb tethering](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/usb-tethering/info), which is used to establish TCP/IP over USB. See e.g. [How to set up reverse tethering over USB?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2298/16575) / [How do I enable USB tethering on a JellyBean device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/28536/16575)

Comment: I still think my question is phrased correctly..... I am looking for an app which I think I have found now called PAW server. However I require it to work via USB not Wifi. My question is has anyone done this? and has anyone found an app that can do this?

Comment: Again, this is not a question of "an app", but of "a connection". Given you can connect to your device using TCP/IP via USB, it doesn't much matter what app is running a web server there. But if you insist on an app, please keep in mind that questions like *Is there an app for X* are off topic here (see our [hepl/on-topic] for details).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android Debug Bridge (ADB, contained in the Android SDK) to forward the tcp connection:

> adb forward tcp:8080 tcp:8080

Comment: This works perfectly fine. I had an Android device on a different WiFi network than my Linux PC - and I wanted to be able to connect to a web server running on Android (a normal Android App with an internal Java HTTP server).  I was able to do the adb forward - then the browser on my Linux system I would point to http://127.0.0.1:8080 - of course other ports can be proxied too.  Really it works similar to a ssh port forwarding.