# Allowing a computer to connect to wifi from android  already connected to wifi. A unique situation

Tags: wi-fi, usb, tethering

writing from my phone so sorry for typos.

I recently fixed my laptop but the wireless network in my house doesn't work on it (its probably router configuration problem-or at least could be fixed with configuring the router, but I have no access to the router since I am renting).

The network works fine on my sanyo zio which has no money on the account and no plan (so the only thing I can use this phone is for internet if I have wifi access). I want to use my phones ability to connect to the home wi-fi network to connect my laptop to that network (so transfer the home wi-fi to the laptop through my phone). Usb connection or wifi will do as I am pretty sure its input this home wi-fi that doesn't work. So if I turn my zio into a hotspot it should work.

Is there any way to do that?
To make situation better I have vista 64 so kyocera divers for this phone don't work.

Update:
I forgot to mention that for some forsaken reason (I suspect murphy's law) the bluetooth internet  connection on my computer fail s when I try to connect it with my phone. (following instructions on fifox and manually connecting with the blue tooth dial up option which just times out. I'm missing some peripheral bluetooth driver ;/) I can connect to my phone through bluetooth just the internet option fails @.@
.
And I don't think my phone supports the wifi option through fox fi. 
Although I have no way to be sure. When I turn on the hotspot option the internet connects but with limited access (just like my home network but I think its because my phone doesn't tether right not because of my laptop. Ofc I could be wrong) it says that might happen and to just automatically get new ip to fix this problem but that doesn't work also says many phones are not supported for wifi and I don't think this one is.

**update**

I Recently rooted my phone. I tried the apps for the rooted phones but they just want to use 3g network connection. Since I want to connect, through wifi they are quite useless. Anybody has an idea what I could download or do to make this work for me?

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring to is called tethering - using the data connection of your phone to share internet connectivity to another device.

Look for tethering options in the settings > Wireless menu or other locations in case your manufacturer has placed it elsewhere.

Failing that, consider using an app like [FoxFi](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.foxfi) or some other tethering app.

Also, a search on Android.SE reveals a number of similar questions - please use the provided functionality. Here's an answered question that might be relevant - [Can I use my Android device as Wi-Fi Adapter for my PC (i.e. Tethering to PC through USB, but using Wi-Fi not Phone Network)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/can-i-use-my-android-device-as-wi-fi-dongle-ie-tethering-to-pc-through-usb-but?rq=1)

Comment: OP isn't asking this. He doesn't want to share his mobile data. But, he wants to share his Wi-Fi internet.

Comment: That's why I referred him to the question - using WiFi NOT Phone Network. The term "tethering" is technically accurate, even though in this case he wishes to tether his device to his PC.

Comment: `Look for tethering options in the settings > Wireless menu or other locations in case your manufacturer has placed it elsewhere.` ~> It can only share Mobile Data in Android.. And, MobileAP always turns off Wi-Fi adapter mode. So, Wi-Fi internet can't be shared by that..

Answer (score 1):

Without using extra software or rooting your phone (which I am not fully educated about, and could not advise you how to do with with root), there are not many options. I would try either of these options:

You asked to share your device's WiFi connection with your computer. To share this you could do it in one of two ways:

1. Bluetooth - You can tether the WiFi connection to your computer via Bluetooth, which can be found under your device's network settings menu.

or:

2. USB Cable - You can also share the WiFi connection with your computer via a USB cable, which will make your computer think your device is a USB Wireless adapter and connect to the internet in this way.

Due to the Android Software limitations, your device will be unable to share a WiFi connection with another device using the same WiFi device (in your phone). It cannot both connect to one device, and host a network for another using the same 'network card', without some advanced software. Using root, you may be able to find an application that allows you to do the above, or you could use an OTG cable to connect a secondary WiFi adapter to your device which means your device will have access to more than one adapter and a software alternative may be more easily found (if there are hardware limitations in place).

**Good luck!**

Answer (score -1):

You want your Android device to re-broadcast an existing Wi-Fi network to act as a `Wi-Fi Repeater`. Technically, its possible from Software layer, but such implementations aren't available for Android yet.

You can do any of following things now:

1. Do it with pure Linux way (Android is a Linux distro) using Hostapd type software. Installation and configuration wouldn't be easy, by the way.
2. Share Wi-Fi internet using Bluetooth DUN. Its the easiest way. I don't know what difficulties your PC bluetooth is facing, but try [PdaNet](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pn.helper) or [Open Garden](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.opengarden.android.MeshClient) .
3. Turn off Mobile Data and do USB Tethering. It starts to share Wi-Fi internet on some devices. Its not universal method, but see if it works for you or not. You can also use PdaNet for better USB Tethering.

Comment: I guess I'm stuck with option number 1. The option 2 is out because bluetooth dun doesn't work for some reason and I don't think option 3 will work since all the usb tethers that I know of require usb driver. and there is no driver for vista 64.so unless I code one or find a usb tether that doesn't require one then I can't use that option.