# How can I do USB tethering with my Samsung Galaxy S5 with the wifi still turned on?

Tags: wi-fi, usb, samsung-galaxy-s-5, wifi-tethering

How can I do USB tethering with my Samsung Galaxy S5 with the wifi still turned on?

Hello,

So I have checked with my old phone (Samsung Galaxy Ace) and it can do USB tethering just fine with wifi connection still turned on.

But when I try to do the same thing with my Samsung Galaxy S5 and when I click on USB tethering it prompts me "Turning on USB tethering will turn off wi-fi".

What is this nonsense and how can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use my Android device as Wi-Fi Adapter for my PC (i.e. Tethering to PC through USB, but using Wi-Fi not Phone Network)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3134/can-i-use-my-android-device-as-wi-fi-adapter-for-my-pc-i-e-tethering-to-pc-thr)

Comment: Checked that link already, does not solve the problem.